# Kendo UI DropDownList - manually raise close event

Tags: events, kendo-ui, triggers, kendo-dropdown, kendo-combobox

I generate template with dropdown lists and they do not works well. When I scroll down when DDL is opened, options list is not closed but scrolled with screen away from input. How can I manually raise close event? I've tried raise like change event:

```
$("#myDDL").data("kendoDropDownList").trigger("close");
```

but not works ... when I try "change" event instead "close" it's works. Is possible programmatically close ddl on scroll? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should automatically close when you scroll outside of the DDL. If you want to manually hide the scroll area try the following in scroll.

```
$('.yourselector').scroll(function() {
  $(".k-list-scroller").hide();
});
```